# How to make the node js code always run even if the system is shutdown

Tags: node.js, pm2, google-api-nodejs-client, nodejs-server, nodejs-stream

i have created the cron job using node js ,which have to run in the interval of every hour even if the system is shut down. It has to run automatically with out manual invoke of the code .Please help to solve this

i have tried with pm2 but not working as expected.

Comment: pm2 can be configured to start your nodejs server code automatically upon machine boot. In fact, that's one of its main practical purposes.  If you want more help, please provide more details about your specific problem.

Comment: "even if the system is shutdown"? That strongly depends on your operating system and hardware, ie if it is possible to automatically start your machine at certain points in time ..

Comment: _i have tried with pm2 but not working as expected._ you should elaborate that and edit your post, see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

First you should install npm package for crone-job

```
npm i node-cron
```

And then you can follow this code for your automatic job

```
const schedule = require("node-cron");
schedule.scheduleJob("00 02 * * *", 
  function () {
   console.log("The answer to life, the universe, and everything!");
   expected_Function_Name();
});
```

You will get your function output in every day 2pm.

Comment: But that would require that the script is running all the time. Node-cron does no scheduling on the os level. So once the script exits, the schedule is gone ... Furthermore it certainly won't start a turned off machine at a certain point in Time